# How to build python with limited ram?

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.7

I have only 256M of ram on my server and that's not enough to build python3.7. And also I can't download it from repository. So, how can I decrease ram usage during the building?

P.S. I have Ubuntu 16.10 on my server

Comment: I'm actually surprised ubuntu 16.10 would run on 256M ram. (and not `lubuntu`)

Comment: It uses only about 12Mb (there's no gui there)

Comment: Could you build it on another machine and copy the result to your server?

Comment: What are you using that has so little RAM? A Raspberry PI has a 1GB. "Get more RAM" seems like the most practical answer.

Comment: @martineau, but I need to copy a lot of other files. And I don't know which files I need

Comment: I believe the result(s) of the build will be contained within a single root directory, so you could copy that.